# Vertically aligning inline-block elements with different heights

Tags: css, html, banner

I have an HTML page which contains inline-block `div`s with variable heights (marked with `.banner` classes):

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <div id="header" style="margin: 0; width: 100%">
 <div>
   <div class='banner'> ...  </div>
   <div class='banner'> ...  </div>
   <div class='banner'> ...  </div>
  </div>

.banner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

They have different widths and are added at runtime. The site layout looks ugly and the banners are not vertically aligned.

For unknown reasons, the `div` does not start not from the top left corner, but there is some empty space at top. How do you align it and the next banner vertically (e.g. make their bottom lines aligned)?

I'm using jQuery, jQueryUI, and ASP.NET MVC2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.banner {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```